# Repositorio PIP privado

Tags: python

vengo del mundo .Net y últimamente me estoy interesando mucho en Pyhtoh, me he creado algunos módulos para realizar tareas comunes.

Quiero, que al igual que hago en .Net con repositorios nuget privados, poder tener un repositorio propio para que cuando trabajo en nuevos proyecto poder hacer algo del estilo "pip install my_modulo".

Hablando con un compañero pensamos en crear un script que se conectase a github y descargarse la última versión del módulo en la carpeta seleccionada, pero en ese caso, se podría realizar modificaciones sobre el modulo y que luego estas no se replicasen... no se si me explico. Me gustaría tener que ir al proyecto donde tengo dicho módulo para modificarlo, poder crear una nueva versión y poder usar pip para añadirlo a mi proyecto... vamos, como hago con nuget...
¿es posible?

Comment: Puedes probar este gist:
https://gist.github.com/Jaza/fcea493dd0ba6ebf09d3 Un saludo.

Comment: Se puede de varias formas,  eso sí no tengo mucha idea que hace nuget, no me he ido al lado oscuro (.net - java) ,  pero si es posible, ahora te pregunto tienes todos tus módulos configurados y encapsulados (setup.py /dist)

Comment: @DavidCarrera tiene buena pinta, este fin de semana intento mirarlo. Edwin lo que me preguntas, no lo he hecho, basicamente no se ni lo que es... investigaré este fin de semana también. Gracias!